# REQUIRES_NEW transactions in not supported by Spring data gemfire

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-gemfire

I am using v1.7.5 of Spring Data Gemfire with Gemfire 8.2.0. 
While using REQUIRES_NEW transactional propogation, it fails with below error while trying to suspend the existing transaction. It looks like underlying Gemfire transction manager (CacheTransactionManager) supports suspend and resume but the spring data gemfire doesn't. Is my understanding right? if yes, is there a work around or support that will be available in near future?


`Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSuspensionNotSupportedException: Transaction manager [org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTransactionManager] does not support transaction suspension
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doSuspend(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1129)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.suspend(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:579)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:424)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:349)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch!

I have filed JIRA ticket [SGF-598 -

"Add support for suspend and resume in GemfireTransactionManager"](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-598) to enhance the SDG `GemfireTransactionManager` with suspend and resume capabilities on local cache transactions.

I have set the "Fix Versions" for this ticket accordingly.

NOTE: SDG `1.7.x` is no longer supported.  See the [SDG project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) for the most current, up-to-date versions.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Thanks John. It wasn't clear from your Jira ticket on when is the release planned. Do you have an update? If that is going to be longer, we need to come up with a workaround for our system. Pls clarify.

Comment: I set the 'Fix Version' to 1.9.1.RELEASE (Ingalls SR1) which we are planning to release tomorrow CET.  I will not be back porting this enhancement to 1.8.  Generally, and usually, but not always, you can find SD Release Train schedules publicly on the SD Commons Wiki here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls).

Comment: Just an update here, I did not manage to get SGF-598 into the recently minted, new SDG 1.9.1.RELEASE (just released today).